# Pycharm - custom scope for full path

Tags: pycharm

Is there any way to create custom scope which full file path with directories from project root contains 'test' word?

For example:

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/first/second/sample_test/my_file.py
```

should be included because directory sample_test contains 'test' word.

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/first/second/my_test.py
```

also should be included because file contains 'test' word.

Comment: For me this pattern does the job `file:*test*.py` does the job. What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `file:*test*.py` and it covers files and folder as listed in your requirements

[image: listed files]

**Edit-1: 23rd Feb**

For not matching the folders with name test, you can use `file:*test*.py&&!file:*test*/*.py`. See the below results using same

[image: Scope 2]

Comment: Could you provide also pattern for negation of this files(excluding all files which path contain test)?

Comment: Tarun Lalwani - second pattern doesnt work. It should include all files except that which has test in path. For example check.py should be included but my2.py not because it is in m3_test_m2 directory

Comment: Torun Lalwani - i will check this tommorow. I granted bounty for your answer because it will be lost. I need to check this exlude scope and if it works then i will accept this answer.

Comment: @domandinho, thanks, if it doesn't work then let me know will see why it doesn't but I believe this should do the job. Earlier your requirement was a bit unclear

Comment: Torun Lalwani - file:*.py&&!file:*test*/*.py" includes files with test in name but it shouldnt. Solution should also exclude files with "test" in name which are places in project root directory

Comment: Can you help me with a simple example of paths that would get select and paths that would get rejected in your question? Then I can easily test it

Comment: @domandinho, please try this also `file:*.py&&!file:*test*/*.py&&!file:*test*.py`